# Select all from the beginning of the line until a left square bracket

Tags: regex, regexbuddy

I need a regex that will select everything from the beginning of the line until the first left square bracket. In the example below it would match **Lorem**, **consectetur-adipisicing** and **labore et**

```
Lorem [ipsum] dolor sit amet,

consectetur-adipisicing [elit] sed do 

eiusmod tempor incididunt ut

labore et [dolore] magna aliqua.
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Using look-behind and look-ahead:**

```
(?<=^|\n)(.*?)(?=\s?\[)
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<=...)` is positive look-behind, checking that the previous characters match.

`^|\n` is intended to be start of line. Start of text (`^`) or new-line (`\n`).

`.` is any character.

`.*?` is zero or more of any characters. `*?` instead of `*` is non-greedy matching, so it will match up to the first rather than the last bracket.

`(?=...)` is positive look-ahead, checking that the next characters match.

`\s` is white-space, the `?` makes it optional (this is to prevent the space before the `[` from also matching).

`\[` is an escaped `[` (it needs to be escaped since `[` has a different meaning)

Comment: Great answer @Dukeling, very detailed. I'd add \s before \[ just to skip the white space. Btw, this matches **eiusmod tempor incididunt ut**, which is the text from the line which doesn't have the **[** char in it.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Added the `\s`. Are you sure it matches the line without the `[`? This should be prevented with the look-ahead (`(?=\s?\[)`).

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Untick "DOT ALL", then it works as required. Another option is to change the `.` to exclude new-lines (probably something like `[^\n]`).

Answer (score 2):

Why do people use the dot and complicated lookaround constructs when a simple anchor and negated character class will do the trick?

```
(?m)^[^\[\r\n]+(?=\[)
```

If your regex flavor supports it, you can further optimize this regex by making the quantifier possessive:

```
(?m)^[^\[\r\n]++(?=\[)
```

If your regex flavor doesn't support lookahead, include the `[` in the match and use a capturing group to get the part that you want:

```
(?m)^([^\[\r\n]+)\[
```

If your regex flavor doesn't supoprt mode modifiers like `(?m)`, simply turn on the option to make `^` match at line breaks ("multi-line mode") outside the regex.

Comment: You are correct that there is no lookbehind assertion at the start needed, but the one at the end is needed to ensure that there is a `[` following the pattern (your regex matches "eiusmod tempor incididunt ut" wrongly). Also you need the the opening square bracket in your expression not the closing one. I think you meant `(?m)^[^\[\r\n]+(?=\[)`. [Regexr](http://regexr.com?35jtr)

Comment: If lines without any `[` must not be matched, and the `[` must not be included in the match, then you need a lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

try `"[^\[]*"` `[]` means a character set, `^\[` means anything except `[` and `*` repeat any number of times. So combined, it should be your answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most simple version would be:

`(.*?)\[.*`

Comment: Thanks Salgar but it matches the whole line, and not only the words preceding the bracket. When I remove .* and apply (.*?)\[ it does what I asked for, except it includes the bracket in the match, and it shouldn't

Comment: Ah sorry, I assumed you wanted a group match of the initial part. Go with what abasu said in that case.

Comment: Dukeling's expression works like a charm, problem solved, thank you Salgar.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful..

```
^(.*)\[
```

**Simple Example:**

```
my $str ="consectetur-adipisicing [elit] sed do";
my $tmp;
if ($str =~ m/^(.*)\[/) {
    $tmp = $1;
}
print "String upto [: $tmp\n";
```

**output is:**

```
String upto [: consectetur-adipisicing
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It does the thing, but the flaw is that it captures the bracket in the match.

Comment: @TotoKalvera, It will match upto `[` but you will get your required value in `$1`
I've added an sample example in my answer.